# Jenkins iOS Codesigning failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, jenkins

What Jenkins settings need to be configured for it to sign iOS apps for apple mobile devices?  I'm trying to set up Jenkins on a spare MacBook to do CI on a new iOS app for the first time.

- I can build and deploy from the command line
- Jenkins is configured to use the same command as the one that works in the terminal `PATH=~/Qt/5.9.2/ios/bin:$PATH make -j 12 QMAKE_FLAGS="QPROTOC=/Users/admin/projects/build-QObjectProtobufCompiler-Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_clang_64bit-Debug/qprotoc/qprotoc  CONFIG+=iphoneos CONFIG+=device" BUILD_ARCH=ios`
- I set Jenkins to use the same user as the one I am building on the command line with (including changing folder, log, etc ownership)
- this is a qt project (make invokes qmake and then make on the auto-generated makefile)

This is the Jenkins error output I get:

```
 PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/    Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/admin/Qt/5.9.2/ios/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module connect     --output-partial-info-plist /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/connect.build/    Debug-iphoneos/connect.build/LaunchScreen-PartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --target-device     iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 8.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /    Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/Debug-iphoneos/connect.app/LaunchScreen.nib /    Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/connect.xcodeproj/LaunchScreen.xib

ProcessInfoPlistFile Debug-iphoneos/connect.app/Info.plist /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/app/    ios/Info.plist
    cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/    Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/admin/Qt/5.9.2/ios/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/app/ios/Info.plist -genpkginfo /    Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/Debug-iphoneos/connect.app/PkgInfo     -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphoneos -additionalcontentfile /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/    workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/connect.build/Debug-iphoneos/connect.build/Launch-PartialInfo.plist     -additionalcontentfile /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/connect.build/    Debug-iphoneos/connect.build/LaunchScreen-PartialInfo.plist -o /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/    mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/Debug-iphoneos/connect.app/Info.plist

ProcessProductPackaging /Users/admin/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/    REDACTED.mobileprovision Debug-iphoneos/connect.app/embedded.mobileprovision
    cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/    Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/admin/Qt/5.9.2/ios/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-productPackagingUtility /Users/admin/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/    REDACTED.mobileprovision -o /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/    mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/Debug-iphoneos/connect.app/embedded.mobileprovision

Touch Debug-iphoneos/connect.app
    cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/    Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/admin/Qt/5.9.2/ios/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/Debug-iphoneos/connect.app

ProcessProductPackaging "" connect.build/Debug-iphoneos/connect.build/connect.app.xcent
    cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/    Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/admin/Qt/5.9.2/ios/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"


Entitlements:

{
    "application-identifier" = "REDACTED.com.precisionplanting.connect";
    "com.apple.developer.team-identifier" = REDACTED;
    "get-task-allow" = 1;
    "keychain-access-groups" =     (
        "REDACTED.com.precisionplanting.connect"
    );
}


    builtin-productPackagingUtility -entitlements -format xml -o /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/    mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/connect.build/Debug-iphoneos/connect.build/connect.app.xcent

CodeSign Debug-iphoneos/connect.app
    cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin    /codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/    Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/admin/Qt/5.9.2/ios/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Michael Rink (REDACTED)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *"
                      (REDACTED)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign EA9034E507C1108550F4A5269522F7EAA05FDE05 --entitlements /Users/Shared/Jenkins/    Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/connect.build/Debug-iphoneos/connect.build/connect.app.xcent     --timestamp=none /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/Debug-iphoneos/connect.app
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/mobileAppIOS/.build/ios/app/Debug-iphoneos/connect.app: unknown error     -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CodeSign Debug-iphoneos/connect.app
(1 failure)
make[2]: *** [xcodebuild-debug-device] Error 65
```

Comment: I ultimately worked around this by having Jenkins trigger a script which invoked the exact same command line argument that failed when Jenkins called it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to enable the keychain containing the certificates and provisioning profiles for code signing. This can be accomplished by:

```
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k keychainPass keychainName
```

[This](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8797) is a related issue on fastlane's github

[This](https://engineering.upgrad.com/ios-continuous-deployment-with-bitbucket-jenkins-and-fastlane-at-upgrad-699b3b48acca) is the post I wrote to setup the whole pipeline using fastlane and Jenkins