# Build issue using fastlane failed on Jenkins

Tags: ios, swift, jenkins, build, fastlane

I am facing an issue. Build is failing while archiving it succeeded successfully. Below the Jenkins log:

```
    [33m▸[0m [39;1mProcessing[0m Info.plist
[33m▸[0m [39;1mGenerating 'MyApp.app.dSYM'[0m
[33m▸[0m [39;1mRunning script[0m 'Run Script'
[33m▸[0m [39;1mCopying[0m /Users/sanoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ehrdzbsrtcthuraipdvlkghvcjyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/pop.framework
[33m▸[0m [39;1mSigning[0m /Users/sanoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ehrdzbsrtcthuraipdvlkghvcjyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Frameworks/pop.framework
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CodeSign /Users/sanoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ehrdzbsrtcthuraipdvlkghvcjyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Frameworks/pop.framework
(1 failure)
[16:06:32]: [31mExit status: 65[0m

+---------------+-------------------------+
|            [32m[33mBuild environment[0m            |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version   | 2.104.0                 |
| export_method | enterprise              |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS11.4.sdk        |
+---------------+-------------------------+

[16:06:32]: ▸ [35mSigning Identity:     "iPhone Distribution: Network, Inc."[0m
[16:06:32]: ▸ [35m    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 6A0EAAC1D162CA8CEE05F09EF98171DF5 --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,flags --timestamp=none /Users/sanoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ehrdzbsrtcthuraipdvlkghvcjyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Frameworks/pop.framework[0m
[16:06:32]: ▸ [35m/Users/sanoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ehrdzbsrtcthuraipdvlkghvcjyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/adhoc/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Frameworks/pop.framework: errSecInternalComponent[0m
[16:06:32]: ▸ [35mCommand /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1[0m
[16:06:32]: 
[16:06:32]: [31m⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error[0m
[16:06:32]: [33m  For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:[0m
[16:06:32]: [33m  /Users/sanoj/Library/Logs/gym/MyApp-adhoc.log[0m
[16:06:32]: 
[16:06:32]: [31mLooks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project[0m
[16:06:32]: [31mIt's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how[0m
[16:06:32]: [31mto troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/[0m
[16:06:32]: [31mBefore submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make[0m
[16:06:32]: [31msure your project is set up correctly.[0m
[16:06:32]: [31mfastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the[0m
[16:06:32]: [31mthe full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.[0m
[16:06:32]: [31mMake sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there[0m
[16:06:32]: 
+------------------+----------+
|        [33mLane Context[0m         |
+------------------+----------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios      |
| PLATFORM_NAME    |          |
| LANE_NAME        | ci       |
| BUILD_NUMBER     | 1.14.467 |
| VERSION_NUMBER   | 1.14     |
+------------------+----------+
[16:06:32]: [31mError building the application - see the log above[0m

+------+---------------------------------+-------------+
|                   [32mfastlane summary[0m                   |
+------+---------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                          | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform                | 0           |
| 2    | Switch to configure lane        | 0           |
| 3    | app_name                        | 0           |
| 4    | update_app_identifier           | 0           |
| 5    | increment_build_number          | 1           |
| 6    | increment_version_number        | 1           |
| 7    | Switch to distribution_app lane | 0           |
|    | [31mgym[0m                             | 118         |
+------+---------------------------------+-------------+

[16:06:32]: [31mfastlane finished with errors[0m
[31m
[!] Error building the application - see the log above[0m
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level /Users/sanoj/jenkins/workspace/MyApp-1.14/fastlane/xcov_report to /JENKINS_HOME/home/jobs/MyApp-1.14/htmlreports/Code_Coverage_Report
Build step 'Upload to HockeyApp' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You should reformat that log output as code - it is pretty unreadable right now.

Comment: do you have adhoc scheme in your code ?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201976/4042468) is an answer I just wrote for a similar question.

Comment: @ Shauket Sheikh yes I have.

Comment: I have updated the question with more detailed log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TroubleShooting steps:

1. Check you are using correct scheme. Scheme should be exist in Xcode configuration.
2. Use manual Signing Style reason is it require permission for Signing.
3. Move your certificate from login to System from Keychain.
4. Change configuration Enterprise to enterprise.

Comment: I am following these above comments, I have searched and followed mostly but this time I am having strange issue. xcodebuild is failing itself.

Comment: Can you paste log here

Comment: Your answer helped me, I was facing the same code signing problem, and the third step "Move your certificate from login to System from Keychain" did the trick! Thank you very much.