# Fastlane error 65 on Jenkins or remote login

Tags: ios, fastlane

I am aware this is known issue, and answers were attempted couple of times, but this time I found conditions which I feel are strange. The logs tell the dreaded **Error 65** and `errSecInternalComponent` when code-signing first Pod.

- When running on Jenkins, my build **FAILS**.
- When running manually on CI machine, logging via SSH and executing `bundle exec fastlane appstore`, it **FAILS**
- When I log in on remote desktop, or physically access the CI machine, build **SUCCEEDS**.

I have `security unlock-keychain` command included in shell script to right before building.

```
bundle update
export FASTLANE_DISABLE_COLORS=1
export APP_IDENTIFIER=com.example.MyApp
security unlock-keychain -p topsecret ~/Library/Keychains/codesign.keychain && bundle exec fastlane appstore
```

I also tried other voodoo, like [doing other magic with keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201976/4042468)

When ran directly on CI server console (or via remote desktop) it runs flawlessly, not prompting for user passwords etc. **I wonder what makes the difference?**

Fastlane version is **2.106.0** (up to date).

The build fails like for other users, when executing Embed Pods Frameworks:

```
▸ Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/ci/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackOffice-gprttmucbsbjiifnxdulcnwierfb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BackOffice_AppStore/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/BackOffice.build/Release-iphoneos/BackOffice.build/Script-7E4F6707694226143D2E7E0B.sh
(1 failure)
[15:59:39]: Exit status: 65

+---------------+-------------------------+
|            Build environment            |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version   | 2.106.2                 |
| export_method | app-store               |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS11.4.sdk        |
+---------------+-------------------------+

[15:59:39]: ▸ total size is 481485  speedup is 1.00
[15:59:39]: ▸ Code Signing /Users/ci/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackOffice-gprttmucbsbjiifnxdulcnwierfb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BackOffice_AppStore/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//BackOffice.app/Frameworks/ACEExpandableTextCell.framework with Identity iPhone Distribution: MyCompany Inc. (XXXXXXXXXX)
[15:59:39]: ▸ /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign CB480CDBA0169C56DA9597D6941095F254D89B3B  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/ci/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackOffice-gprttmucbsbjiifnxdulcnwierfb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BackOffice_AppStore/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//BackOffice.app/Frameworks/ACEExpandableTextCell.framework'
[15:59:39]: ▸ /Users/ci/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackOffice-gprttmucbsbjiifnxdulcnwierfb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BackOffice_AppStore/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//BackOffice.app/Frameworks/ACEExpandableTextCell.framework: errSecInternalComponent
[15:59:39]: ▸ Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Could you fix this?

Comment: Annoying problem for me. I solved this problem by reinstalled the whole macos system, but I met it again soon.

Comment: with jenkins ,u can use keychain and profile plugin to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Jenkins server. To fix it I used the following flag in my match action

```
keychain_password: "my_Mac_Password"
```

I took it out once I was able to make it work once.

You can also try the [unlock_keychain](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/unlock_keychain/) action if you are not using match.

Comment: How did you manage to add this value in `gym` ? It tells that it's an invalid property. And I can't see it in the docs : https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/

Comment: @c4k Sorry. It isn't a gym flag, but an action. So you need to add it before the gym call. https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/unlock_keychain/

I also updated my answer since I had it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix `errSecInternalComponent` error with temp keychain:

1. Delete your signing certificates and private keys (!) from your login keychain (or other keychains)
2. Automize creating temp keychain in your Fastfile:

```
FASTLANE_TEMP_KEYCHAIN = 'fastlane_temp_keychain'
KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = 'temppassword'
```

```
if File.exist?(File.expand_path("~/Library/Keychains/#{FASTLANE_TEMP_KEYCHAIN}-db"))
  delete_keychain(
    name: FASTLANE_TEMP_KEYCHAIN
  )
end
create_keychain(
  name: FASTLANE_TEMP_KEYCHAIN,
  password: KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD,
  unlock: true,
  timeout: 0
)
```

3. Import your certificate and private key

```
import_certificate(
  certificate_path: certificate_path,
  keychain_password: KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD,
  keychain_name: FASTLANE_TEMP_KEYCHAIN,
  log_output: true,
)

import_certificate(
  certificate_path: p12_certificate_path,
  keychain_password: KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD,
  keychain_name: FASTLANE_TEMP_KEYCHAIN,
  log_output: true,
)
```

4. Install provisioning profile:

```
install_provisioning_profile( path: provisioning_profile_file_path )
```

And you should be good!
They question was asked 4 years ago but my answer could be helpful to somebody. I've spend plenty of time dealing with this issue.